# What's the difference between bias in model error in regression?

Tags: regression, variance, bias

Is model error the same as bias in regression? For example, if I construct data by $y_i=N^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial plus uncorrelated noise, and do a regression with the $M^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial, is the 'sweet spot', where bias + variance is minimized, at $N=M$?

Comment: @PeterEllis has provided a good answer below. Let me add one small detail regarding your concluding question (which I suspect might have been an oversight): It depends on how much data you have. Eg, if you use an 8th degree polynomial, your model would be saturated if you had only 10 data.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here.

The answer to your general question is "no", model error is not the same as bias.  Bias is the difference between the expected value of your estimator and the true parameter.

In many instances of model error, the parameter will not even feature in the model.  With a bit of effort you could reparameterise your model so that it has the parameter in it implicitly, perhaps forced to have a value of zero (if it is a linear model) so you can say that the expected value of your estimator is zero, which unless that is also the true value, is a bias of sort.

Alternatively, the model might look fine with regard to your particular parameter of interest but be misspecified elsewhere, which will lead to biases in the estimate of your parameter of interest.  So yes you can generally express the problems of model error as leading to bias in an estimate of one or more of your parameters.

It doesn't work as a general equation "...the same as..." however.  There is lots wrong with model error other than just bias.  And bias can come about from a particular estimation technique even if the model is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm having a hard time following some aspects of your response. First, the definition of bias makes it appear like we need to know the true parameter. Also, in the simple case of regression -- fitting a polynomial -- doesn't the use of a model with a polynomial of degree too small have model error as well as bias?

Comment: @JohnFInn - Yes in both cases.  Bias is normally thought of in terms of "if XX were the true model, and we had YY as our model (which may or may not be the same as XX) and used estimation method ZZ, what would the difference be on average between the estimate and the true parameter?"  So either model misspecification or estimation method may lead to bias.